# Jmeter script not started immediatly after clicking Run button

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 3.1.

While I am trying to run the script & click on run button on GUI mode. Script doesn't start/executed immediatly. It took 1 or 2 mins to start executing the script.

Please let me  know if anyone faced such Issue earlier & how can I Overcome from this issue.

Comment: Show your test plan. You might enter timers/delays

Comment: No. there is no timers/delay in my test plan.